# Masking an image in Erdas using Thematic Image, the mask comes out looking wrong and completely different than input image

Tags: erdas-imagine

I am trying to mask out shadows and clouds in a WV2 8-band image. I classified an image to identify the shadows and clouds and then using the mask took in erdas used the classified image to mask out the specified pixels in the input image using "setup recode". The first time I did this the image came out looking great. The second time it came out looking hazy, the color map was off, and just all around did not look good. I did the exact same steps as I had the first time and now I can't get the mask to come out right. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I just don't understand because I did the exact same thing as I did when it came out right and yet I am getting a different output.

[image: First try at mask, came out correct]
[image: Second try came out looking like this.]

Comment: What is the bit depth of your images before and after the mask?

Comment: Before the mask it is unsigned 16-bit and after the mask it is still unsigned 16-bit. The mask that worked came out as an unsigned 16-bit as well.

Comment: Please consider adding your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, it was just the image statistics. I needed to ignore 0's when computing image stats and it came out fine.